# Amazon S3 with s3fs and fuse, transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mount, s3fs

Redhat with Fuse 2.4.8
S3FS version 1.59

From the AWS online management console i can browse the files on the S3 bucket.
When i log-in (ssh) to my /s3 folder, i cannot access it.
also the command: "/usr/bin/s3fs  -o allow_other bucket /s3"
return: s3fs: unable to access MOUNTPOINT /s3: Transport endpoint is not connected

What could be the reason? How can i fix it ? does this folder need to be unmount and then mounted again ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Well, the solution was simple: to unmount and mount the dir. The error `transport endpoint is not connected` was solved by unmounting the s3 folder and then mounting again.

**Command to unmount**

```
fusermount -u /s3
```

**Command to mount**

```
/usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other bucketname /s3
```

Takes 3 minutes to sync.

Comment: on some machines, `umount -f` would be a more available command for the first part.

Answer (score 15):

I don't recommend to access s3 via *quick and dirty* fuse drivers. 
S3 isn't really designed to act as a file system, 
[see this SOF answer for a nice summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801158/how-stable-is-s3fs-to-mount-an-amazon-s3-bucket-as-a-local-directory)

You would probably never dare to mount a Linux mirror website just because it holds files. This is comparable

Let your process write files to your local fs, then sync your s3 bucket with tools like cron and s3cmd

If you insist in using s3fs..

```
sudo echo "yourawskey:yourawssecret" > /etc/passwd-s3fs
sudo chmod 640 /etc/passwd-s3fs

sudo /usr/bin/s3fs yours3bucket /yourmountpoint -ouse_cache=/tmp
```

Verify with `mount`

Source: http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon

Answer (score 2):

I was using old security credential before. Regeneration of  security credentials (AccessId, AccessKey) solved the issue.

Comment: I was trying to mount Wasabi S3, and for that I had to use `-o url=https://s3.wasabisys.com`

Answer (score 1):

This was a permissions issue on the bucket for me. Adding the "list" and "view permissions" for "everyone" in the AWS UI allowed bucket access.

If you don't want to allow everyone access, then make sure you are using the AWS credentials associated with the user that has access to the bucket in S3Fuse

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and i found that the bucket can only have lowercase characters. Trying to access a bucket named "BUCKET1" via the https://BUCKET1.s3.amazonaws.com or https://bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com will both fail, but if the bucket is called "bucket1", https://bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com will success.

So it is not enough to lowercase the name for you the s3fs command line, you MUST also create the bucket in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Just unmount the directory and reboot the server if you already made changes in /etc/fstab which mounts the directory automatically.

To unmount  `sudo umount /dir`

In /etc/fstab these lines should be present. then only it will mount automtically after reboot

```
s3fs#bucketname /s3 fuse allow_other,nonempty,use_cache=/tmp/cache,multireq_max=500,uid=505,gid=503 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be due to policy attached to IAM user. make sure IAM user have AdministratorAccess.

I have face same issue & by changing policy to AdministratorAccess issue got fixed.