# Amazon S3 with s3fs and fuse. script to unmount and mount

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

Redhat with Fuse 2.4.8
S3FS version 1.59

In addition to: [Amazon S3 with s3fs and fuse, transport endpoint is not connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010115/amazon-s3-with-s3fs-and-fuse-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected)

I would like to make a script to fix the situation. The script will unmount and mount the the directory. the commands i need to use are:
fusermount -u /s3
/usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other bucketname /s3

For people who familiar with this situation, should I be concerned with something else ? or this is enough ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use amazon s3 as a unix file system in a productive environment. S3 is not built like this. From the [s3fs docs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon)

> Important Limitations
>   Eventual Consistency
>   Due to S3's "eventual consistency" limitations file creation can and will occasionally fail. Even after a successful create subsequent reads can fail for an indeterminate time, even after one or more successful reads. Create and read enough files and you will eventually encounter this failure. This is not a flaw in s3fs and it is not something a FUSE wrapper like s3fs can work around. The retries option does not address this issue. Your application must either tolerate or compensate for these failures, for example by retrying creates or reads. For more details, see Eventual Consistency

Comment: just realized you already got this advise of mine :D Sorry for the sermon.

Answer (score 0):

Good read.

I think to circumvent, my 2-cents worth is that you could do a minute-ly cron to copy files from the mounted S3 drive to your server. If the context suits, that is