# AWS: Mounting S3 bucket to EC2 via s3fs (iam role) executes but does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I set up a RoboMaker project on AWS. When I am on the virtual desktop of my development environment, I would like to work with the files from my S3 bucket. I figured mounting the S3 bucket via `s3fs` is the best option. When using the `aws s3` CLI I can interact with the buckets from the EC2 instance without any problem, but for my current project I need them to be mounted.

I followed [this](https://cloudsbaba.com/how-to-mount-s3-bucket-with-ec2-linux-instance-using-iam-roles/) tutorial. My command to mount the bucket finally looks like this:

`s3fs my-bucket /path/to/local/folder -o iam_role="my-mounting-role" -o url=https:/s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com -o endpoint=eu-central-1 -o use_path_request_style -o allow_other -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000`

Now the command apparently executes without any problem, but when I look in my local folder where the bucket should be mounted to it is still empty. This confuses me a little, since even when I change the bucket name to something which does not exist or if I change the iam role to something which does not exist, the command still executes without error feedback. I am a bit lost where to start looking for the error. Is there some s3fs expert out here who could help me troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest to keep the design right and not use any kludges which might hurt the scalability or maintenance factor of the application. Check this answer as to why s3fs is not a good solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14010199/970422

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon S3 with s3fs and fuse, transport endpoint is not connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010115/amazon-s3-with-s3fs-and-fuse-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still do not know the exact reason for the behavior, however, I launched a new EC2 instance with the necessary iam role permissions (apart from RoboMaker) where it just worked..

Answer (score 0):

try foreground and debug option while mounting. -f --debug