# deploy java application on aws

Tags: mysql, tomcat, amazon-web-services

i have a web application running on tomcat7 and mySql, now i want to deploy it to aws..

the application need to write file on disk (such as images uploaded by users)

some one can help me pointing out how to configure a good infrastructure in aws for my need?

i read this: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/ , i think that my needs are an EC2 instance for running tomcat and an Amazon RDS whit mySql...

i need something else for R/W file ?

i need to change my code in some way in order to make it work on aws?

thanks in advance,
Loris

Answer (score 0):

Elasticbeanstalk is a good way to get started with an application deployment at AWS. For persistent file storage you can use S3 or an EBS volume.

S3 allows you to read and write using amazon's SDK/API. I am using this on a java application running at AWS and it works pretty smoothly. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html

It is also possible to mount S3 over NFS, you can read some interesting points in this answer:
[How stable is s3fs to mount an Amazon S3 bucket as a local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801158/how-stable-is-s3fs-to-mount-an-amazon-s3-bucket-as-a-local-directory)

With EBS you can create a persistent storage volume attached to your EC2 node. Please note that EBS is a block level storage device so you'll need to format it before its usable as a filesystem. EBS allows you to help protect yourself from data loss by configuring EBS snapshot backups to S3.
http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/

-fred

Comment: just wondering if you have a solution to simailr problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431130/how-do-i-configure-data-files-in-a-autoscaled-multi-instance-elastic-beanstalk